# Rails 2.3.8 causing js call to ImageController forget current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

After upgrading from rails 2.1.2 to 2.3.8 the call to imagecontroller through an applet(within a js function) no longer has stored current_user data available. This is causing the image to not load. Not sure why on making the most minimal changes for this upgrade this just stopped working.

Comment: Please show the code you have and all other context necessary to answer the question... but my first inclination would be to explore the cookie/session changes between versions.

Comment: JavaScript function:                                                            document.write('<param name="page" value="' + file_location_of_image + '">')   This results in a call to http://localhost/suburi/directory_of_image/image.jpg                                                           There is a route setting to handle directory_of_image to do a "send_data" with the image but with a before filter :login_required. The login_required returns false because current_user gets reset

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code...

The JavaScript function:
document.write param name="page" value="' + file_location_of_image +

This results in http request : http://localhost/suburi/directory_of_image/image.jpg

There is a route configuration to handle the action "directory_of_image" that in turn calls a "send_data" with the image after a before filter :login_required. The login_required returns false because current_user gets reset at this point and the image never gets back to the browser.

Comment: Hello, the main issue I feel is happening here is that the session info is somehow getting reset at the time the JS function is making a http request with the help of an applet. Does anyone know why this is happening so? Is this a bug in rails 2.3.8? If yes, then am wondering what the workaround would be. Thanks!